# Disable buttons while the mp3's they trigger are playing

Tags: pi-3, python, rpi.gpio

I am using this python script to use 2 buttons to trigger 2 different mp3 files in a museum exhibit. As the files are 30 minutes long, I have also added a stop button to stop the playing mp3 so that the user doesn't have to listen to the end before listening to the other track. This is all working perfectly.

But I now need to disable the 2 trigger buttons for the duration of the audio tracks, otherwise the tracks can be played over the top of each other with multiple button pushes. (Kids.)

I tried to do this by increasing the sleep command which I assumed was in seconds, to be the same length as the audio file, but this didn't work. Is there another way?

I am also open to the idea of a 2 button system where each button press kills whatever mp3 is playing, then plays the selected mp3.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import subprocess
from time import sleep

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    if (GPIO.input(23) == False):
        subprocess.Popen(['mpg123', 'audio1.mp3'])
        sleep(1)

    if (GPIO.input(24) == False):
        subprocess.Popen(['mpg123', 'audio2.mp3'])
        sleep(1)

    if (GPIO.input(25) == False):
        subprocess.call(['killall', 'mpg123'])

    sleep(0.5);
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the subprocess kill before the two calls that play the mp3? You may need a short sleep in between.

Comment: This is not a Pi question - it is general programming. Just make any button press kill whatever is playing before starting new.

Comment: @Milliways thank you, I realise that now. My apologies for posting in the wrong place, and thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @Steve Robillard Thank you so much, this did the trick. Seems obvious now that you have suggested it. I very much appreciate both your help and your patience.

Answer (score 2):

OK here's the working script, big thanks to Steve Robillard.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import subprocess
from time import sleep

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    if (GPIO.input(23) == False):
        subprocess.call(['killall', 'mpg123'])
        sleep(0.1)
        subprocess.Popen(['mpg123', 'audio1.mp3'])

    if (GPIO.input(24) == False):
        subprocess.call(['killall', 'mpg123'])
        sleep(0.1)        
        subprocess.Popen(['mpg123', 'audio2.mp3'])


    if (GPIO.input(25) == False):
        subprocess.call(['killall', 'mpg123'])
```

The killall subprocess in each of the two buttons makes the 3rd killall button (GPIO 25) redundant as well, which is nice, simplifies everything.